# Jquery loop through only those inputs which has values in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to loop through form fields and add the value of each input and show the total in another div. It is working for me only if I fill all the form fields. How I can make it work if I have values only in my 2 form fields?

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav tabs " id="calculate">
      <li class="active"><input type="text" class="col-sm-3 pull-right" id="right-input"></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">    <input type="text" class="col-sm-3 pull-right" id="right-input"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><input type="text" class="col-sm-3 pull-right" id="right-input"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab"><input type="text" class="col-sm-3 pull-right" id="right-input"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab"><input type="text" class="col-sm-3 pull-right" id="right-input"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab"><input type="text" class="col-sm-3 pull-right" id="right-input"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab"><input type="text" class="col-sm-3 pull-right" id="right-input"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab8" data-toggle="tab"><input type="text" class="col-sm-3 pull-right" id="right-input"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab9" data-toggle="tab"><input type="text" class="col-sm-3 pull-right" id="right-input"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab10" data-toggle="tab"><input type="text" class="col-sm-3 pull-right" id="right-input"></a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("input").keyup(function() 
    {
        var $inputs = jQuery('#calculate :input');
        var values = {};
        var total = 0;
        $inputs.each(function() 
        {
            if(values[this.name] !== "") 
            {
                total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(values[this.name]);
            }
            if(total)
        });
        console.log(total);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do little change in you `each()` loop like this:

```
$inputs.each(function () {
         if ($(this).val() !== "") {
             total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($(this).val());
         }  
     });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/wttgqg11/1/)

Comment: Welcome Baig bhai...:) glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the input before loop, this will give you inputs where value is not empty.

```
 var $inputs = jQuery('#calculate :input').filter(function(){return this.value !==''});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change how you add up your values, try this:

```
var value = !isNaN(Number(values[this.name])) ? parseFloat(values[this.name]) : 0;
total += value;
```